# Git stuck on asking me for SSH password

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

This suddenly started happening today. I tried pushing to my Gitlab repo and git asked me for my SSH password as it usually does; I entered it correctly, and it asked for it once more. After I entered it again it asked me for my git username and password. I entered those correctly too, but it just kept asking for those on repeat. I can't push now because it just keeps asking for my login info.

This is on Linux, I SSH'd into my repo and have the two SSH files in ~/.ssh.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I feel like the tag [tag:git] might be a little bit out of scope for the question. Can you tell us if this is a company GitLab account, if you are behind proxy and such?

Comment: It is a company Gitlab and I am behind a proxy

Comment: Can we assume you already contacted your network manager and reported the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> This is also with Gitlab, not Github. Git is also already storing my username and password.

Git does store your username/password only for HTTPS URLS

> I used the SSH clone url for my repo.

That means HTTPS credential caching, or proxy are not in play here.

Check if your SSH key is *passphrase* protected.
An SSH URL would never result in asking *your* username: said username is always "`git`": `git@<server>:<me>/<myrepo>`, the private `id_rsa` key being used by GitLab to authenticate you.

Check if anything has changed, maybe in your environment variables (and '`*SSH*`' one?), or in your SSH files (the protection on `~/.ssh` or its content might have changed, depending on your OS), or in `~/.ssh/config` if you have one.